# Change subpage name with Visual Editor

Tags: mediawiki, visual-editor

I've a page with subpages, it looks like this (just an example, not my real data) :

```
-page
  ↳ apple
    ↳ iPhone
    ↳ iPad
  ↳ samsung
    ↳ Galaxy
```

By default the title of the iPhone page is `page/apple/iPhone`. With the code editor and the [Display Title extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Display_Title), I can change the page name with `{{DISPLAYTITLE:iPhone}}`. Is there a way to change it with the visual editor in order to be easier for my contributors ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing really to do with the Diplay Title extension, the magic work `{{DISPLAYTITLE:}}` is part of MediaWiki core.

VisualEditor is already capable of changing the display title, without the need of any additional extensions or configuration. You can change the title by (when the VisualEditor is already "started"):

- click the three-lines-menu (hamburger menu) at the top right
- Choose "Advanced settings"
- The input field `Title styling` allows you to change the title

[image: example from en.wikipedia.org]